# sed command to replace second occurrence of xml tag

Tags: regex, xml, bash, sed

I have a sample config.xml file which is as follows:

```
<maven2-moduleset>
  <actions/>
   <jdk>JDK 6 Update 26</jdk>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher plugin="sonar@2.1">
      <jdk>jdk1.8</jdk>
    </hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher>
  </publishers>
</maven2-moduleset>
```

I wanted to change the second occurrence of `<jdk></jdk>` tag. So i used sed command to do that, as shown below:

```
sed -i "s/<jdk>\.*<\/jdk>/<jdk>jdk1.7.0_76<\/jdk>/2" config.xml
```

But there was no changes in that file. Where am i going wrong?

Note: second occurrence of jdk tag can contain any jdk version. I want to replace any value(version) mentioned in that tag to this value="jdk1.7.0_76".
and, 
i cant use perl or xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern will match literal any number of literal `.` between the tags, and that's it, which isn't what you want. Additionally, you're appending a 2 because you want to match the second occurrence of the `jdk` tag pairs, but this would only work if your two pairs of `jdk` tags appeared on the same line.

If you want to match anything containing a single period somewhere between the `jdk` tags then this will work:

```
sed -i "s#<jdk>.*\..*</jdk>#<jdk>jdk1.7.0_76</jdk>#" config.xml
```

This will only replace the second `jdk` tag pair because the first one doesn't contain a `.` which is matched in the regex above with the `\.`.

You could also match anything not containing a space:

```
sed -i "s#<jdk>[^ ]*</jdk>#<jdk>jdk1.7.0_76</jdk>#" config.xml
```

This works because only the second instance in your example lacks spaces.

Finally you could tell sed to only replace the `jdk` tag that appears between the `hudson` tags:

```
sed -i "/<hudson/,/<\/hudson/ s#<jdk>.*</jdk>#<jdk>jdk1.7.0_76</jdk>#" config.xml
```

I used the `#` instead of `/` for the search delimiter because unlike `/` it doesn't appear in the regex.

Comment: Plus one for suggesting how to write strict rules. (e.g. `jdk[0-9.]*` in place of `.*`) & "match only between hudson" was a good one.

Comment: so very well explained @julian. Thanks. it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you can use this sed command:

```
sed -i "s/<jdk>jdk.*<\/jdk>/<jdk>jdk1.7.0_76<\/jdk>/g" config.xml
```

This should replace any `jdk[version]` string within jdk xml tags with your own jdk version.

But, I'd suggest you do it using `awk`.
This should do the trick:

```
awk '/<jdk>.*<\/jdk>/{c+=1}{if(c==2){sub("<jdk>.*</jdk>","<jdk>jdk.1.7.0_76</jdk>",$0)};print}' config.xml > config_new.xml
```

It looks for the second occurence of the `<jdk></jdk>` xml tags and then replaces the version.

Comment: I know you're more focused on solving the problem with awk, but your sed solution will not solve the problem for the sample input due to the leading spaces in the input and your use of ^ in the solution.